SignalR way to avoid cross API call
we're creating our first SignalR dedicated .net API.
So we're basically beginners on this matter ;-)
The way I see it, we'll use it in two distinct ways :

Message sent from a Web/Mobile client application and received by another Web/Mobile client application
Message sent from an API (not our SignalR API) and received by a Web/Mobile client application

The first one seems to be the normal usage of SignalR.
The second one is a little bit more tricky.
The example that is shown in Microsoft Documentation involves dependencies between our APIs and the SignalR API, because its url must be provided.
Like this :
using (var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://www.contoso.com/"))
{
    IHubProxy stockTickerHubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("StockTickerHub");
    stockTickerHubProxy.On<Stock>("UpdateStockPrice", stock => Console.WriteLine("Stock update for {0} new price {1}", stock.Symbol, stock.Price));
    await hubConnection.Start();
}

I don't like this kind of dependencies. The only one we have is with Identity Server, and caused us a lot of issues !
It could probably be achieved through service bus, but we don't have any for the moment.
So I was thinking : is there a way to dispatch such messages through a database ?
I mean : the source API don't need a real maintained long term connection.
All it needs is to put the message somewhere and move on (it's just an event that happened, a notification, not a discussion)
Does anything like this exist already (nuget package) ?
Or is there a built in way to avoid this cross api call that I've missed ?
Thanks in advance for your help.
As previously mentioned, all this is new to us.

You could put the connection implementation into a nuget package. Inject it as a scoped service. Use observer pattern to invoke methods on it in response to events. Raise events in it when you receive messages. I've found this approach to work well. You still need to initialize the url for the hub connection (usually from appsettings). Is this the sort of thing you are looking for?

@PeterDongan I've seen that SignalR was already writing messages in a database table (we use the SQL Server package). So I was thinking, instead of a call from any api to the SignalR api, maybe I could simply store the message in the database and SignalR would poll it ? I really don't need real time for these events, just propagation to the client.
But I don't know if it would imply writing this whole behaviour from scratch.

Yes, you would need to write the code to poll the database, because it is not a standard approach. You wouldn't really be reducing dependencies with this approach because your SignalR service would be dependent on the database. This approach would also be inefficient because it would introduce a bunch of database calls. Raising and consuming events, via whatever mechanism, strikes me as the natural approach to achieving what you are aiming for.

I think you are trying to avoid a long-time connection between the API and the Signalr API but you do have many messages in API and hope the Signalr API to help deliver to the clients. At first, I come up with an idea that you can exponse an endpoint in Signalr API which is used to receive messages and transfer them to the required clients. Then your API could call this endpoint. But you don't want it, want to make your API to store the messages into the database, and ask the Signalr API to monitor the

database and then get the messages and transfer them. I'm afraid this is also not a good idea since it will bring pressure to database. In your scenario, the message queue might be a better option. Let's assume we are using the message queue, the API could write messages into the queue, the there shall be a queue trigger to resent the message to the endpoint exposed by Signalr API. It shall be ok but if there're plenty of messages, it will bring pressure to the Signalr API server, in this scenario, we might need to use long-running connection. It depends on your business logic.

Hi guys, thanks for your reply. @TinyWang in fact, it's quite the opposite. The events I refer to will be rare (compared to real time communication between web/mobile and SignalR api). Our database is - in our system - the steadiest place. No need to manage timeout (except for standard one), no fear of loss of messages. And, in a back developer local environment, there would be no need for the SignalR API to be up and running for the other apis to work (in the other case, the developer would be blocked because of a message he does not even care about)

thank you for your reply and the confirmation. No other concerns in this question right?

@TinyWang you're right. It was my concern at the start, but it seems that there's nothing that suits my needs out of the box. We'll have to implement another layer based on bus messaging to be able to send messages from our api without connecting them (and thus binding them) to the SignalR API. Looks like this project is getting suddenly more expensive, because as I've said before, we don't have such layer anywhere now. Thank you both for your advices.
